# Access values in multidimentional Swift array?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, firebase, swift2

I'd like to populate a tableView with results from a Firebase query. I successfully get the results and store them into an array but I'm struggling with how to put those values into the table.

I'm getting back a "userID" and a "title". I'm storing those in an array `[[String]]`. An example of an array after getting back a value would be `[["OYa7U5skUfTqaGBeOOplRLMvvFp1", "manager"],["JQ44skOblqaGBe98ll5FvXzZad", "employee"]]`

How would I access an individual value, such as the userID? This is what I have so far in my cellForRowAtIndexPath function:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        let invite = inviteArray[indexPath.row]
        print(inviteArray)
        print(invite)

        return cell
    }
```

Thanks!

EDIT: added function to store snapshot in an array

```
var dictArray: [Dictionary<String, String>] = []

func getAlerts(){

    let invitesRef = self.rootRef.child("invites")
    let query = invitesRef.queryOrderedByChild("invitee").queryEqualToValue(currentUser?.uid)
    query.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in

        for child in snapshot.children {
            guard let invitee = child.value["invitee"] as? String else{
                return
            }
            guard let role = child.value["role"] as? String else{
                return
            }

            self.dictArray.append(child as! Dictionary<String, String>)
            print(self.dictArray)

        }
    })
}
```

Comment: You can chain array access like: array[1][2]. But why is this an array of arrays in the first place? An array of structs seems more appropriate

Comment: I do not understand / see the problem! Does `invite[0]` not work?

Comment: Yea I'm starting to think that this data type isn't ideal. How does an array of structs work?

Comment: can you add your current observing value/child code so that we can suggest improvement in it.

Comment: You don't need a multi-dimensional array. Firebase snapshot.value is (can be) a dictionary. Just store these dictionaries in an array. When you are populating the tableview, access them  let dict =myArray[indexPath.row]. Then, to get a persons name:  let user_id = dict["userID"] and let name = dict["name"]. Then populate yours cells textfield with cell.textField.stringValue = user_id etc.

Comment: Hi Jay, thank you very much for the reply (sorry for my delayed response). What is the best way to store the snapshot? I created an array of data dictionaries and when I try to append to that array I get an error `Could not cast value of type 'FIRDataSnapshot' to 'NSDictionary'`. Updated the code in my question. Thanks!!

Comment: Can you show how your populating the array?